# Can the stringize macro be used here?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification, pelles-c

Using Pelles **C** I would like to show or log an unsigned char array.
Is it possible to use the stringize macro to show the whole array as hex values instead of iterating through the array with `printf(%x)`?

Answer (score 1):

No. Stringification only encloses the specified parameters within double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't. Stringification can convert your identifiers to strings, but not vice versa. Also, it can do nothing to the value a variable contains(neither read nor write), because values can be determined at run time, and macros expand at compile time.

In fact, I think preprocessor tricks such as `#` and `##` should be avoided if possible, because they greatly reduce the readability. `#include`, `#define` and `#if` are enough for the most time.